# "I haven't done something in a long time before now" vs. "I hadn't done something in a long time before now"?

Tags: difference, present-perfect, past-perfect

Can you please tell me if I need to use the present perfect or the past past perfect in the sentence below?

> **I haven't eaten** any sweets in a long time before now.
>
> **I hadn't eaten** any sweets in a long time before now.

Generally I'm aware of when to use the tenses, but this context is giving me a hard tieme. Are both sentences perfectly natural? If so, is there any difference in meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Before now* is superfluous in both sentences. *I haven't done X in/for a long time* implies 'until now'.

The past perfect doesn't make sense unless you are talking about the past.

> I went to see the Royal Shakespeare Company's *Hamlet* last week. I hadn't been to the theatre for a long time. ('before that' is implied).